# How to get print the console log in variable?

Tags: javascript

I would like to output:

```
[2, [23]]
```

however, when I run:

```
console.log([2,[23]]);
```

I get:

```
(2) [1, Array(1)]
```

---

I have tried to use the `toString()` method, but I got `'2,23'` instead.

Comment: `var example = "[2,[23]]"`

Comment: in Firefox you could simply do `[2, [23]].toSource()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get the exact same representation (not least because it varies from environment to environment), but `JSON.stringify` will get close:

```js
var s = JSON.stringify([2,[23]]); // s gets "[2,[23]]"
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createTextNode(s)
);
```